KVM CPU Passthrough Frequencies
I am looking at a KVM server and client, and noticed something I don't really understand and I'm hoping someone can enlighten me/point me in the correct direction.
cat /proc/cpuinfo shows - among other things - the following on the server -
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x49
cpu MHz     : 3500.000
cache size  : 30720 KB

But the kvm clients are showing
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x49
cpu MHz     : 2596.990
cache size  : 16384 KB

Note the difference in cpu MHZ.   It appears to me that the cpu MHz figures match the model name frequency in the client - which is, according to Intel Ark for the CPU, roughly the base frequency, but the frequency on the host is the max turbo frequency.
The VM clients are using CPU Passthrough (ie "Copy host CPU configuration(hostpassthrough) mode), and the topology is NOT manually set.
The CPU governor is set to "performance" on the host.   (Somewhat embarrassingly still using Rocky Linux 8.10)
I was a little put out that that it is not possible to see - let alone change the governor on the virtual machines (The host is Running Ubuntu 22.04)
So my questions (which are all really part of trying to understand the same thing) are -

Should the VM hosts mirror the VM server CPU frequency?
Are the values in the host meaningful?  (I notice they all appear to be locked at 2596.99, while on the host they seem to vary, presumably depending on the current load)
Can the guest burst beyond the base frequency, and if so is there anything I can set to make this happen?

